# Treat files like both files and directories in FUSE?

Tags: unix, filesystems, fuse

It's kind of a strange (but completely justified) use-case for FUSE, but is there a way to trick programs running on top of a FUSE filesystem implementation to list all entries as files, but allow reading the "files" as directories as well?

For instance, is there a way to get a FUSE filesystem to behave in the following way?

```
$ cd mnt
$ ls
foo bar

$ cat foo
Some foo text!

$ pwd
/mnt

$ cd foo
$ ls
qux qix

$ cd qux
$ pwd
/mnt/foo/qux

$ cd ..
$ pwd
/mnt/foo

$ cat qux
Some Qux text.
```

Is there a way to do this by exploiting a symlink file mode, or is there a similar way? Or is this completely impossible and I should go another route?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such thing would be possible, because file/directory operations would start with requesting the type of the object. And the system cache could include and report only one type at a time. So you won't be able to tell the OS that the entry is both a file and directory. Moreover, most applications have checks like "if IsFile then ... else ... " , so they would just miss the second attribution.